# Finite order elements of quotient group ${G}/{G^m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, quotient-group

> Let G be a group such that for some integer $m>1$, $(ab)^m=a^mb^m, \; \forall a,b \in G$, and let $G^m=\lbrace a^m: a\in G\rbrace$. Show that $G^m \triangleleft G$ and order of each element of ${G}/{G^m}$ is finite.

*$\underline{Claim: G^m \triangleleft G}$*

Let $a$ be an arbitrary element of G and choose $h$ in $G^m$,$\;h$ has the form $h=b^m$ for some $b \in G$. Now, consider:

$$ab^ma^{-1}=\underbrace{(aba^{-1})(aba^{-1})(aba^{-1})...(aba^{-1})}_{m\;times}=(aba^{-1})^m\in G^m$$
It follows that for an arbitrary $a$ in $G$ we have $aG^ma^{-1} \subseteq G^m$. This implise $G^m \triangleleft G$.

*$\underline{Claim:\text{Every element of } {G}/{G^m} \text{has finite order}}$*

Since $G$ is a group and $G^m$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ we can talk about $ {G}/{G^m}$ as a quotient group(factor group). WLOG, let $g^m \in G^m$ then

$$g^mG^m = G^m \text{, since } aH=H \iff a\in H $$

This implies that $$g^m =e$$
Implies every element in a quotient group has finite order.

Do I make any mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped!

Comment: Well, $G^m \triangleleft G$ means that $G^m$ is a normal *subgroup* of $G$. You forgot to prove that $G^m$ is a subgroup of $G$ (and that’s why we need that $(ab)^m=a^mb^m$ for every $a$ and $b$ in $G$).